# 'T' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program that implements the functionality of a stack. My code is the following:

```
class StackOfNodees
{
private:
    Node<T>* m_top;
    int m_size;

public:
    StackOfNodees();
    bool isEmpty() const;
    int size() const;
    void push(T value);
    T pop();
};
```

Node.hpp

```
template<typename T>
Node<T>::Node()
{
    Node.setPrevious(nullptr);
    Node.setValue();
}

//initiation of getters
    template<typename T>
    T Node::getValue()
    {
        return m_value;
    }//end getValue

    template<typename int>
    int Node::getPrevious()
    {
        return m_previous;
    }//end getPrevious

//initiation of setters
    template<typename void>
    void Node::setValue(T value)
    {
        m_value =  value;
    }//end setValue

    template<typename void>
    void Node::setPrevious(Node<T>* previous)
    {
        Node<T>* previous = m_previous;
    }//end setPrevious
```

I get the error:

```
‘T’ was not declared in this scope|
```

Can anyone help? Also if someone could explain what template is used for that'd be great too.

Comment: you need to add template<> declarations in your class in order for it to know what T is

Comment: ... or write `Node<int>* m_top;` whatever you intend to do there.

Comment: I have those in my .hpp file. I'll add that to the op.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it stands, `StackOfNodes` has no idea what `T` is.   T can be anything, as far as the compiler knows. So you have to give `StackOfNodes` a templated type `T` so it can reference it within the class.

For example, the code would something like this:

```
template<class T>
class StackOfNodes
{
 ... // code

};
```

Even though `Node` has a type T, `StackOfNodes` does not. Until you add that templated type, the compiler can't assume anything. Once that is added in, the code should compile (with regards to the error mentioning T)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put

```
template <typename T>
```

before the `class` statement.

Comment: which class statement? 
`class StackofNodees`?

Comment: Yes, see `Alejandro Lucena`'s answer